# Finding Min and Max numbers in a txt file

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

See the below photo for reference:

[image: pic1]

I have a problem in finding the min and max number in .txt file.
The number is stored in a file as one number per line. The Programm should go through these numbers and find the biggest and smallest number.

**Update**: I solve this problem, but I face another issue due to the type of numbers.
Let say I have the following numbers:
0005.00
0005.23
52340.53
0000.01
0111.10
0001.00
2523.00

How can I get the right answers?

```
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int counter=0, number;
float  sum = 0, average=0;
char file_name [20];
cout << "enter filename: ";
cin >> file_name;
ifstream input;
input.open(file_name);
if (! input)
{
cout << "Can't open file" << file_name;
//exit (0);
}

input  >> number;
float min = number;
float max = number;

while (input>>number)
{
counter++;
sum=sum+number;
// Now, we can also check for Min/Max...
if (number > max) max = number;
if (number < min) min = number;
}
average=sum/counter;

cout<< fixed<<cout.precision(3);
cout<< "The average file in file test is was "<<average<<endl;
cout<< fixed<<cout.precision(3);
cout<<"The largest number is: "<<max<<endl;
cout<< fixed<<cout.precision(3);
cout<<"The smallest number is: "<<min<<endl;
input.close();
return 0;
}
```

When i run it, the min and max values are zero! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop reads all numbers in the file:

```
while (input>>number)
{
    counter++;
    sum=sum+number;
}
```

After that loop, `input` is already at the end of the file and the next loop will not read any numbers.

Read the numbers once and do all processing in a single loop. Alternatively, store the numbers in a `std::vector` and then work on that.

Moreoever, you never modify `Min` and `Max` in your code. What this loop:

```
while (input>>number)
{
    if (number>Max)
    number=Max;
    else
    number=Min;
}
```

does instead is to clip the numbers such that any number bigger than `0` (`Max`) is set to `0` and any other number is set to `0` (`Min`).

You probably want something along the line of

```
double number;
input  >> number;
double min = number;
double max = number;
while ( input >> number)  {
   if (number > max) max = number;
   if (number < min) min = number;
}
```

I used the first number to initialize `min` and `max`. If you don't to that, `0` is no good initial value for `min` and `max`, but you can use `std::numerical_limits<double>::min` as initial value for `max` and `std::numerial_limits<double>::max` as initial value for `min`.

Comment: It works! thank you. But i face another issue.. If i have the following numbers (two digitsafter comma and four digits before comma): 0005.00
0005.23
52340.53
0000.01
0111.10
0001.00
2523.00  how can i get the right answers? I got weird results..
Altough i used the foolowing :  cout<< fixed<<cout.precision(3);
cout<< "The average file in file test is was "<<average<<endl;
cout<< fixed<<cout.precision(3);
cout<<"The largest number is: "<<max<<endl;
cout<< fixed<<cout.precision(3);
cout<<"The smallest number is: "<<min<<endl;

Comment: @Katreen what is "weird results" ? btw I mistakenly assumed you are working with `int` numbers, will fix that

Comment: yes, you are right. but i want to use other type of numbers.. for integers it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Your first `while` loop will read to the end of file; thus, your second `while` loop won't actually read anything - you will already be at the file's end before it starts.

You should incorporate the code that is the 'body' of the second loop into the first one, and remove that 'redundant' second loop. You are also assigning the `Min` and `Max` variables the wrong way round:

```cpp
while (input>>number)
{
    counter++;
    sum=sum+number;
    // Now, we can also check for Min/Max...
    if (number > Max)
        Max = number;
    if (number < Min)
        Min = number;
}
average = sum / counter;
```

You should also give your `Min` and `Max` better initial values (unless you know there will be both positive and negative numbers in the data):

```cpp
float number, sum = 0, average, Max = -FLT_MAX, Min = FLT_MAX;
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i still have the same issue!

Comment: @Katreen Did you make **all** the code changes? (Also, I made a small error, which I have just corrected, in the initial values.) You should set the initial `Min` to `FLT_MAX` and the initial `Max` to the negative of that, or `-FLT_MAX`.

Comment: It works! thank you. But i face another issue.. If i have the following numbers (2 digits after comma and four digits before comma): 0005.00 0005.23 52340.53 0000.01 0111.10 0001.00 2523.00 how can i get the right answers? I got weird results.. Altough i used the foolowing : cout<< fixed<<cout.precision(3); cout<< "The average file in file test is was "<<average<<endl; cout<< fixed<<cout.precision(3); cout<<"The largest number is: "<<max<<endl; cout<< fixed<<cout.precision(3); cout<<"The smallest number is: "<<min<<endl;

Comment: @Katreen Use `setprecision(3)` instead of `cout.precision(3)`. What you currently have is calling the `precision` function and then writing its returned value to the output stream.

Comment: @Katreen Or you can still call that function but not output it: `cout << fixed; cout.precision(3);`. And you only need the first of those lines in the code; the settings will remain until changed.